# Bulk import/load csv to sqlite using Python

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, bulk-load

i have searched for a method to do a bulk import of a csv to sqlite using python script.

Currently i am using an insert which runs for every row of the csv:

```
with open('file_name.csv','rb') as fin:
        Read_csv = csv.DictReader(fin) # comma is default delimiter
        to_db = [(i['col1'],i['col2'],i['col3']) for i in Read_csv]
        DbCur.executemany("INSERT INTO table (col1,col2,col3) values (?,?,?);",to_db)
```

I need a method to bulk insert the entire data instead of inserting row by row which i think is not very optimized coding.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a table like this:

```
class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__="Sample"
    X=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Y=Column(Integer)
    Z=Column(Integer)
```

Suppose you have the following data in a file named "test.csv":

```
X,Y,Z
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

You can do bulk import, given that no duplicates in your data and no duplicates in your existing table:

```
import pyexcel as pe

...
pe.save_as(file_name="test.csv", dest_session=session, dest_table=Sample)
```

Here is the complete code for bulk import to sqlite:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column , Integer
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
import pyexcel as pe

engine=create_engine("sqlite:///tmp.db")
Base=declarative_base()

class Sample(Base):
    __tablename__="Sample"
    X=Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Y=Column(Integer)
    Z=Column(Integer)

Session=sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
session = Session()
# produce test csv
adict = {
    "X": [1, 4],
    "Y": [2, 5],
    "Z": [3, 6]
}
sheet = pe.get_sheet(adict=adict)
sheet.save_as("test.csv")
# end production
# bulk import
pe.save_as(file_name="test.csv", dest_session=session, dest_table=Sample)
result = pe.get_dict(session=session, table=Sample)

# verify result
print(result)
```

In real world, columns are of differnt types, so you may want to [format your columns](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial03.html) after [loading csv file](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.org/en/latest/generated/pyexcel.get_sheet.html#pyexcel.get_sheet) before the bulk upload.

Comment: you are creating adict with all the values of the csv? I have lots of records in my csv.

Comment: @user1474157, am creating a list of dicts, [{"X": 1, "Y":2, "Z":3}, {"X":...}]. How big is your data set?